# ArangoDB - how to import neo4j database export into ArangoDB

Tags: neo4j, arangodb

Are there any utilities to import database from Neo4j into ArangoDB? `arangoimp` utility expects the data to be in certain format for edges and vertices than what is exported by Neo4j.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is not an answer per se, but a comment wouldn't allow me to structure the information I gathered in a readable way.

Resources online seem to be scarce w/r to the transition from neo4j to arangodb.

One possible way is to combine APOC (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures) and neo4j-shell-tools (https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools)

1. Use apoc to create a cypher export file for the database (see https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/export-sub-graph-to-cypher-and-import/)
2. Use the neo4j-shell-tool cypher import with the `-o` switch -- this should generate csv-files
3. Analyse the csv-files,

   1. massage them with `csvtool` OR
   2. create json-data with one of the numerous csv2json converters available (npm, ...) and massage these files with `jq`
4. Feed the files to arangoimp, repeat 3 if necessary

There is also a graphml to json converter (https://github.com/uskudnik/GraphGL/blob/master/examples/graphml-to-json.py) available, so that you could use the afforementioned neo4j-shell-tools to export to graphml, convert this representation to json and massage these files to the necessary format.

I'm sorry that I can't be of more help, but maybe these thoughts get you started.